# Почему "непрошенный гость" пишется с двумя буквами "н"?

Tags: орфография

Слово образовано от глагола несовершенного вида "просить".Так почему же?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, кто-то ввёл Вас в заблуждение: НЕПРОШЕНЫЙ пишется с одной Н. Образовано от глагола несов.вида, приставки, кроме не-, нет, зависимого слова нет. Не сомневайтесь, пишите с одной.

Comment: Спасибо,Екатерина :)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел по поисковикам, откуда ветер дует.

Александр Дюмин вас обманул? Там, вроде, ошибка в авторской версии. Это случается.

А вот как прокатчики пропустили ошибку в переводе названия индийского фильма - это уже симптоматично.

Comment: Не перестаю удивляться... Отлично!

Answer (score 0):

Непрошеный гость, незваный гость - всё с одним "н".